# Tool/Program/Script/Formula for deciphering Active Directory Connection Strings for 3rd party user integration?

Tags: active-directory

We're using WSFTP, which has an Active Directory Integration module. To populate the user accounts you need to provide a connection string akin to:

- OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com
- CN=Domain Users,OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com

Questions:

- Is there a Tool/Program/Script/Formula that allows me to decipher how these strings might look based on what I can see in Active Directory Users & Computers?
- Is there a proper/accepted name for these types of connection strings? I don't even know what to Google to get more information about how to format one properly
- How would I troubleshoot the connection string if I think it looks correctly formatted, but it isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: I figured out that the name for these types of connection strings is "Distinguished Name" or (DN)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on LDAP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol

Those are LDAP Distinguished names.

As to how they look in AD, lets take this simple structure:

```
mydomain.local
|
|-- UserContainer
  |
  |-- userA
```

the DN for this user would be: `CN=userA,OU=UserContainer,dc=mydomain,dc=local` (note I'm not using the default "users" container, that little bestie is a Microsoftism, and not a real container. In AD it's actually a CN (aka a leaf object, that magically has users in it instead of the container (OU) object it should be ... grrrr))

Comment: ADSIE.msc (run from server with adminpak.msi installed. It will show you the LDAP name of any object in active directory. Works Great!

Answer (score 0):

Tool to browse LDAP [link text][1]

[1]:   [1]: http://www.ldapbrowser.com/"Softerra LDAP Browser"

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 2003/2008 or workstation with RSAT you could use dsquery command. It gives you ldap path for object.

```
dsquery user -name USER_COMMON_NAME
```

`USER_COMMON_NAME` is not equal your user login, I don't remember, but probably it is equal description field from your `Active Directory Users and Computers` console.

Alternatively, you could use ldapsearch command from linux box (but first, you must configure openldap library in /etc/openldap/ldap.conf). I don't remember its syntax, but you must provide some account with password (Bind account) to bind to ldap from your Active Directory.

Here is [link to article](http://www.windowsserverfaq.org/?url=/faq/ADQueries/LDAP-Queries.asp) about LDAP in Windows